# out of memory issue with PHP script

Tags: php

My PHP script is running out of memory. I have put memory_get_usage( ) inside the loops and found that it is running out of memory after 6MB.
I would like to clearly explain my script and like to get suggestions from you.
I am not sure, If my script is running out of memory because of problems with code .
So, here is the algorithm for my script:

1. Read the input json data into an array ( approximatley 200 lines of data)
2. calculate the sum of the array ($sum)
3. 3 variables $starting, $ending and $compare.( Intialize $compare = $starting)
4. start with $starting=$vmin , calculate scaling factor, scale the original array and calculate sum of it .That new sum is $ending.
5. Add 10 to $starting until the diff between $ending and $compare is 50.
6. repeat all the steps until $vmin reaches $vmax with an increment of $vinc

The above algorithm might look insane, But it finds an optimal solution for supply chain related optimization problem.
I would like you to see if my weak coding capabilities are the reason for the memory outage .If so, Please suggest the changes to my script.
Here is my code

```
$vmax = 10000;
$vmin = 1000;
$vinc = 2000;

//decode the json data                                             
$fp = fopen("data_save3.json", "r");
$inp=file_get_contents("data_save3.json");
fclose($fp);
$inp=json_decode($inp);

//calculate the array sum          
foreach($inp as $i=>$element) {
    foreach($element as $j=>$sub_element) {       
        $sum+= $inp[$i][$j];
    } 
}    
//start at vmin and increment it until vmax
for(;$vmin <=$vmax;) {
    $starting=$vmin;
    $compare = $starting;
    //calculate scaling factor
    $scale = $starting/$sum; 
    //calculate the scaled array  
    $sum2 = 0;
    $inp_info2 = $inp;    
    $ending = newscale($inp_info2,$scale,$sum2);
    $optimal = getClosest($starting,$ending,$compare,$sum);
    echo $optimal.PHP_EOL;  
    $vmin = $vmin+$vinc ;
}
// function to find the closest value
$inp_info1=$inp;
function getClosest($starting,$compare,$ending,$sum,$inp) {
    global $sum2;
    global $compare;
    global $inp_info1;
    global $starting , $ending, $scale1, $sum, $inp, $inp_info2, $inp_info3,$rowsum2,    $rowsum3, $rowsum4, $rowsum5;
    if (abs($ending - $compare) < 50){
        return $starting;
    } else{    
        $starting = $starting +10;  
        $scale1 = $starting/$sum;
        $inp_info1 = $inp; 
        $sum2 = 0;      
        $ending = newscale($inp_info1,$scale1,$sum2); 
        return getClosest($starting);
    }
}
//array scaling function        
function newscale($array,$scale,$sum2){
global $sum2,$scale;
foreach($array as $i=>$element) {
    foreach($element as $j=>$sub_element) {         
        $array[$i][$j]*= $scale;   
        $array[$i][$j] = truncate($array[$i][$j]);
        $sum2+=$array[$i][$j];
    }     
}
return $sum2;
}    
//truncate function
function truncate($num, $digits = 0) {
    $shift = pow(10, $digits);
    return ((floor($num * $shift)) / $shift);
}
```

Comment: can you show the json data?

Comment: The only place in you code that I see the opportunity to store large amounts of data would be in the `newscale()` function, however 6MB memory usage isn't exactly breaking the bank. How big is your input data?

Comment: I have added json data sample to my post. Thanks

Comment: My input data is 200 rows * 14 columns

Comment: `getClosest` could be the culprit. Recursive function calls are always a good place to start when getting an out of memory error.

Comment: I approached our server guys to make changes in the php.ini file to avoid memory outage, but, they informed me that, they can't do anything like that.. If I don't get this to work, I am planning to create a c++ executable , If that helps with memory outage.Does that sound like a good idea or is there any way i can optimize this php code?Please help

Comment: I also thought that the getClosest function is creating all this. But,I don't know how to do this otherwise

Comment: I'm not having problems executing this as is.  Although the code seems complicated, intentional or not...I am unfamiliar with how php handles function arguments having the same name as globally scoped variables, or returning an instance of the function being called like you've done in the getClosest() function.

Comment: I'm not very good at coding in PHP. The function that I am trying to achieve is complicated.when i execute this script, It is giving 2 output values and going out of memory..for example ( it is giving output for $vmin = 1000 and 2000 , then it is going out of memory)..are you able to get those 10 output values??

Comment: 1000 3000 5000 7000 9000 is the output I get, 200 OK, and no errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: The output should be 1240,2720...etc..It calculates array based on sum of the original array and $vmin,, its a bit complicated..I am getting those two values and then getting memory outage

Comment: unless its intentional, you don't need to call `global $starting;` in getClosest() because your passing it $starting as an argument.  Maybe you want to pass your function arguments by reference? `function getClosest(&$starting, ...`

Comment: ohh ok, could you please edit my code and paste it as an answer..

Comment: I am not good at using pointers or references. so, some body please edit my code to pass arguments by reference for getClosest() function.. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48513/discussion-between-user2791530-and-humbolight)